# how to consume web services (own project) from html page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services

i have a web service project called (WS_Service)
i have a html page thats trying to consume WS_Service.

i have web services sits on its own project (the reason i have created is because its independednt and can be called from .aspx or .html or mobile)

i dont have problem with .aspx and i have just add the reference and fire the services.

but i am not sure how i will be doing on .html page below is my code i am trying to POST to a web service:

```
 $.ajax({ 
      type: "POST", 
      url: "http://myhostname/Delete.asmx/DeleteCustomer",  <<< is that right?
      data: "{CustID: " + parseInt(customer_id) + "}", 
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
      dataType: "json", 
      success: function(msg) { 
                     AjaxSucceeded(msg); 
               }, 
      error: AjaxFailed 
 });
```

any suggustions?

Comment: What is the problem with this code? Are you getting an error? What do you expect to happen and what is the actual outcome?

Comment: ok here is what i got Fiddler: DNS Lookup for school_ws failed. No such host is known

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you can't POST to a form that's on another domain using AJAX. So make sure that you aren't trying to POST to domain1.com when the Javascript is running on domain2.com.

Assuming they are on the same domain, you are pretty close, but if you're trying to post JSON to using jQuery I would just do something like this:

```
var data = {
    CustID: parseInt(customer_id)
};

$.post("http://myhostname/Delete.asmx/DeleteCustomer", {data: JSON.stringify(data)}, function(response) {
  //success
});
```

That will send through your JSONified object in a POST variable called `data` on the server side of things.

Don't try to mess with building the JSON yourself in a string, that will get very messy if you start sending complicated data. That's why they invented the JSON functions. `$.post` is just a shortcut to `$.ajax` with some default stuff already configured that should be fine for your use. If you really need to capture AJAX errors (like HTTP Status Codes), have a look at `$.ajaxError` as a supplement.

You can include a simple JSON compatibility script in your page if you are supporting legacy browsers that don't have the JSON.stringify and JSON.parse functions, like https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: It's not necessary to call JSON.stringify because jQuery will do that for you.

Comment: both are on the same domain, okay i try to post dont get anything, how do catch succes or failure?

Comment: @Pointy Oh, I wasn't aware of that. I thought if you passed an object, jQuery would turn it into POST variables, not a JSON string?

Comment: @Abu Hamzah Have you tried using Firebug (http://getfirebug.com/)? It will show you exactly what is being passed back and forth between the Javascript and your server. Whatever your server is returning (as long as it's returning a 200 OK HTTP Response Code) will be stored in the `response` variable in the success function.

Comment: i forgot about that FF, but i want to display the response that i get from WS and display that to the user.

Comment: @Riley well that's a good point - it depends on what the server expects. *Usually* the server wants a plain ordinary HTTP request, with a list of name/value pairs, but it's definitely possible that what a server wants is a single parameter whose value is a blob of JSON. Can't really tell in this case, but there'd still need to be a parameter name somewhere.

Comment: ok here is what i got `Fiddler: DNS Lookup for school_ws failed. No such host is known`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect strongly that this line:

```
  data: "{CustID: " + parseInt(customer_id) + "}",
```

should involve an object, not a string:

```
  data: { CustID: customer_id },
```

or possibly:

```
  data: { CustID: parseInt(customer_id, 10) },
```

Comment: Yes, my interpretation of that was that they were trying to build a JSON string themselves.

Comment: I am not sure If I am correct but If you go look at the api documentation it says it is ok to use the string because it actually get's changed by default when it gets sent: "The data option can contain either a query string of the form key1=value1&key2=value2, or a map of the form {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}. " http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @TBohnen.jnr yes but what's in the OP is **not** a query string.